# What are the elements in the event in $E \cup F$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Event $E$ is defined as the amount of loss for property values of homes in the price range of $100,000$ to  $500,000$. Event F is defined as amount of loss is greater than $250,000$.

I think the union of these two events would be amount of loss for property values from $100,000$ all the way to an infinite price value. This upper bound makes me doubt my answer.

Comment: Just because there is no upper bound does not imply that there are actually occurrences of infinite loss of property value.  All this is is that $E\cup F$ happens to be all outcomes corresponding to loss of property value greater than (*or equal?*) to $100,000$, whichever of those values happen to occur in the sample space.

Comment: "This upper bound makes me doubt my answer."  But it didn't make you doubt the definition of $F$ as " amount of loss is greater than 250,000"?  If $F$ has no upper bound why does the lack of upper bound of $E\cup F$ give you pause?

Comment: But You added the words "all the way to an infinite price value" yourself.  No-one else did. It is no more or no less a part of the definition of $E\cup F$ than it is of the definition of $F$.  It is exactly, no more no less, reasonable to refer $E\cup F$ going "all the way to an infinite price value" as it is to refer to $F$ as going "all the way to an infinite price value". ... to be continues.....

Comment: ....continued..... As there's no such thing as an infinite house value, it'd probably be more accurate to describe $F$ as the losses on house valued greater than $250,000$ to the most expensive houses in the area and $E\cup F$ as  on the houses of value $100,000$ to the most expensive houses in the area.  But the words "to the most expensive houses in the area" are not at all necessary. Simply saying greater than $100,000$ is enough.

Comment: Actually are you sure you copied the problem correctly.  what you wrote is $E$ is "the amount of loss for property values of homes in the price range of 100,000 to 500,000" that is the losses, regardless as to amount, based on the values of the houses.  And $F$ is "amount of loss is greater than 250,000 that is losses based on the ammounts, regardless of the values of the houses.  These are inconsistent but not impossible.  $E\cup F$ would be the losses on houses valued between 100,000 and 500,000 or on losses over 250,000.  That's a possible answer but I dont think it is the intended answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Event $E$ is defined as the amount of loss for property values of homes in the price range of 100,000 to 500,000. Event $F$ is defined as amount of loss is greater than 250,000.

Then, $E\cup F$ is the amount of loss greater than 100,000 (and therefore extending towards infinity).

> This upper bound makes me doubt my answer.

$F$ is the amount of loss from 250,000 *up to infinity*.  So there is no reason to doubt when it occurs in your answer too.